# QSqlRelationalTableModel and autocomplete field (PyQt4)

Tags: python, autocomplete, combobox, pyqt4

I have created a single-field tableview using QSqlRelationalTableModel. The only field in this tableview is taken from a table (mysql) with a long list of names. What is the right way to create an autocomplete when I write a name in the field which is logically connected with a query "like".

```
self.model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()

self.model.setTable("archlibri")
self.model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
self.model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Autore")
self.model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Titolo")
self.model.setRelation(1, QtSql.QSqlRelation("elAutori", "aID", "aNome"))
self.model.select()

tabella.setModel(self.model)       

tabella.setItemDelegate(QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(tabella))
```

Tabella is a QTableView. The column "Autore" (column have relation delegate) is where i want add a autocomplete when i write a name

Comment: Can you be more specific? You have a single column `QTreeView`. You want to have autocomplete where exactly? In the same tree view, while editing items?

Comment: i have edit the question with more information. I hope they are sufficient.

Comment: it's still not clear what you are trying to achieve here, please post more code

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of field your author field is you would have to implement a query that selects author names from the database with what the user types in. Eg. Hemingw... the query goes select... where.. name like %placeholder. The value returned you would set to the author field in your ui. You need to do this together with a signal data changed.